# MySQL most recent n entries, ascending?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I'm trying to get a list of the n most recent entries into a database, but sort them ascending.

Obviously I can use the following to get the first n entries:

```
SELECT owner_id,message 
FROM messages
WHERE thread_id = ? 
ORDER BY time ASC
LIMIT ?
```

Or this to get the most 5 recent, descending:

```
SELECT owner_id,message 
FROM messages
WHERE thread_id = ? 
ORDER BY time DESC
LIMIT ?
```

But how can I get the most recent 5 in ascending order? I can just reverse the order of the array in PHP, but that seems a little inefficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Select * from
(SELECT owner_id,message,time 
FROM messages
WHERE thread_id = ? 
ORDER BY time DESC
LIMIT ?) test
Order by time ASC
```

**[Sample fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/048cd/1)**

Comment: Thanks, this looks to be on the right track, but I'm getting errors from it. I'm being told "Unknown column 'time' in 'order clause'" when trying to access the time column of the test alias. I tried to access it as test.time, but MySQL wouldn't accept that either.

Comment: edited. Look now. You should get time field also in temp result set

Comment: Haha, I guess I should have been able to figure that one out myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
select owner_id,message from (
    SELECT owner_id,message,time 
    FROM messages
    WHERE thread_id = ? 
    ORDER BY `time` DESC
    LIMIT ?
) temp
order by time ASC
```